# Hiding File and folders, and harddisk partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, files, autohide

How can we hide the file and folders with the terminal commands?
Can we even hide the hard disk partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of Linux, any file or directory that's name starts with a `.` is considered hidden.

Note that hiding a file or directory is *not* a measure of security, it's just for convenience, so that unnecessary files such as configuration files don't bother your daily routine. They can be listed easily if you wanted, e.g. `ls -lA`.

As for hiding partitions, you can use `gparted` to set a "hidden" flag on partitions. This will hide the partition from operating systems. Note that this can be easily reverted, so *don't* use this for hiding sensitive data.

If you want to operate on the same disk you're booting from, you might need a live CD/DVD or (preferably) a live USB stick.

*If you are looking for security, search this site (or Google) for encrypted folders and partitions.*

Comment: THank you this is simply the best thing I learnt today about linux

Comment: @algosig I'll just add a funfact: [According to Rob Pike](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp), hidden files were an unintended consequence of trying to make `ls` not show `.` and `..`. Essentially, a bug that turned into a feature.